# Is there any simple function to re-size the image which stored in database to let visitors see small image instead of original size

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need some help with re-sizing an original high resolution image to a smaller image for security through an easier function.

I already have used the function `file_get_contents( $image )` before I INSERTed it into MYSQL with LONG BLOB format.

Now, I am able to display those images with given dimensions through the height and width attributes of the  HTML tag, now that displayed images are downloadable (i.e. savable through right click & save image option) with their original size.

So, I need to use a function to change the dimension of that image before display. Is there any possibility to keep the image as a thumbnail?

I don't want to keep two images (one for thumbnail and other for the downloadable image in  the database).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked PHPs GD library?

[`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is one of the functions you could use

Comment: Thanks @ Frits van Campen. I haven't seen, i will now.